# Unwanted space between parbox and following paragraph in custom command

Tags: cv, parbox

I've created a custom command for CV entries. Unfortunately, the spacing between those entries is different, if there is only one line of text in the parbox. The following image shows the problem.
[image: Different Lineheight]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[%
    a4paper,
    fontsize=11pt,
    parskip=half-,
]{scrartcl}

\areaset{32em}{51\baselineskip}
\reversemarginpar
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{8em}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{1em}

\newcommand*{\cventry}[6]{%
    \par\raggedright{%
        {\leavevmode\marginline{\small{#1}\par}}%
        {\bfseries{#2}}%
        \ifx#3\else{, #3}\fi%
        \ifx#4\else{, #4}\fi%
        \ifx#5\else{, #5}\fi%
        .%
    \ifx#6\else{\newline{\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\small\itshape#6}}}\fi%
        \pagebreak[1]
    }%
}%

\begin{document}
    \cventry{07/2019\,--\,08/2019}{Jobtitle}{Institution}{Location}{Optional}{Comment}
    \cventry{02/2019\,--\,06/2019}{Jobtitle}{Institution}{Location}{Optional}{Very long comment spreading over multiple lines, very long comment spreading over multiple lines, very long comment spreading over multiple lines,}
    \cventry{01/2018\,--\,01/2019}{Jobtitle}{Institution}{Location}{Optional}{Comment}
    \cventry{01/2017\,--\,12/2018}{Jobtitle}{Institution}{Location}{Optional}{Comment}
\end{document}
```

Why is this the case and how could I fix this? What other improvements could I make to my command?

Comment: I'm unable to test, but see two things to question.  (1) the space after `\pagebreak[1]` will cause the line containing the `\parbox` to exceed the width, potentially requiring another line; add `%`.  (2) `\ifx#6\else` compares `#6` with `\else`, which will likely never happen; this won't cause extra space, but will mean that there will not be any valid comparison with the tested argument.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Could that be a trap for `\relax`?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes -- Perhaps.  Would be worth testing for, but I'm not at present able to test.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Upon test, it seems to effectively screen out the comma if you leave the argument blank.  On your hypothesis, it proves false comparing `\else` to the brace and thus converts into a simple `\if...\fi` where the `\else` no longer applies, and so ignores typesetting the comma, etc.  The one catch is if the argument is a single token, then the `\else` still gets sucked up in the compare and the argument goes away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `%` after `\pagebreak[1]`.

I would also add a `\strut` after `\itshape#6`.

```
\documentclass[%
    a4paper,
    fontsize=11pt,
    parskip=half-,
]{scrartcl}

\areaset{32em}{51\baselineskip}
\reversemarginpar
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{8em}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{1em}

\newcommand*{\cventry}[6]{%
    \par\raggedright{%
        {\leavevmode\marginline{\small{#1}\par}}%
        {\bfseries{#2}}%
        \ifx#3\else{, #3}\fi%
        \ifx#4\else{, #4}\fi%
        \ifx#5\else{, #5}\fi%
        .%
    \ifx#6\else{\newline{\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\small\itshape#6\strut}}}\fi%
        \pagebreak[1]%
    }%
}%

\begin{document}
    \cventry{07/2019\,--\,08/2019}{Jobtitle}{Institution}{Location}{Optional}{Comment}
    \cventry{02/2019\,--\,06/2019}{Jobtitle}{Institution}{Location}{Optional}{Very long comment spreading over multiple lines, very long comment spreading over multiple lines, very long comment spreading over multiple lines,}
    \cventry{01/2018\,--\,01/2019}{Jobtitle}{Institution}{Location}{Optional}{Comment}
    \cventry{01/2017\,--\,12/2018}{Jobtitle}{Institution}{Location}{Optional}{Comment}
\end{document}
```

[image]